# Query for replacing a column value in one table by its id in another table

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have two tables employee and department, i want to replace department names from employee table by department id from department using a single query?

Comment: why using a question tag? Thats just a information... Well to know thats fine that you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
update employee e
inner join department d on e.dept_name = d.name
set e.dept_id = d.id
```

Comment: @user1944725: Then you should add a field `department_id` of type `int`, make the update and then drop the `deparment name` column. You don't want to store numbers in a string column, right?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE E AS 
    INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT D 
        ON E.DEPT_NAME = D.DEPT_NAME 
SET E.DEPT_NAME = D.DEPT_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's some issues on how he/she states the problem in here.

But based on what I think and assume about the situation it should be something like this (correct me if I am wrong):

TABLE: Employee

```
|-----------------------------------|
| Id | EmployeeName | DepartmentId  |
|-----------------------------------|
| 1  | Employee A    | 1            |
| 2  | Employee B    | 2            |
| 3  | Employee C    | 1            |
|-----------------------------------|
```

TABLE: Department

```
|--------------------|
| Id | DeparmentName |
|--------------------|
| 1  | Department A  |
| 2  | Department B  |
| 3  | Department C  |
|--------------------|
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
|-------------------------------------|
| Id | EmployeeName  | DepartmentName |
|-------------------------------------|
| 1  | Employee A    | Department A   |
| 2  | Employee B    | Department B   |
| 3  | Employee C    | Department A   |
|-------------------------------------|
```

Question: What is the purpose why you wanted that is it for viewing or record update?

SCENARIO 1:
Because if it just for the purpose of viewing no need to update as the above can be produced using a join query.

```
SELECT e.Id, e.EmployeeName, d.DepartmentName
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Deparment d
ON e.DepartmentId = d.Id
```

SCENARIO 2:
But if it is for record update, there will be an issue as DepartmentId is a numeric datatype while Department name is a string datatype.

```
UPDATE Employee e
INNER JOIN Department d
ON e.DepartmentId = d.Id
SET e.DepartmentId = d.DepartmentName
```

But the above code will cause an error as I mentioned above so you might change DepartmentId with a string datatype so that the above query will be executed without error.

But in this case I think you will only need the first scenario.